# Spring Boot error message doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm writing my first spring boot app and I'm stuck with this problem.  I can't show error message to user. Object without that data is not saved in the database and that is OK. But showing error message is the problem. When I debug i get errors size = 0

This is model

```
@Size(min = 1, message = "Address is invalid.")
@NotNull
@Column
private String address;
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String createNewBusiness(@Valid @ModelAttribute("business") Business business,
                                BindingResult result, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("userEmail", getUserEmail());
    logger.info("/business/create:" + business.toString());
    LocationResponse locationResponse = geoService.getCoords(business.getAddress());

    if (locationResponse.getStatus().equals("OK")) {
        business.setLatitude(locationResponse.getResults().get(0).getGeometry().getLocation().getLat());
        business.setLongitude(locationResponse.getResults().get(0).getGeometry().getLocation().getLng());
        business.setUserId(getUserId());

        businessService.createNew(business);

        model.addAttribute("business", business);

    } else {
        business.setAddress(null);
        model.addAttribute("business", business);
    }

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        List<FieldError> errors = result.getFieldErrors();
        for (FieldError error : errors ) {
            System.out.println (error.getObjectName() + " - " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return "newBusiness";
    }

    return "business";
}
```

Thymeleaf

```
<div class="input-field left m-0 w-100">
    <i class="fa fa-map-marker prefix grey-text" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input placeholder="Address" id="inputAddress" name="address" type="text" class="validate my-0" th:required="true">
    <label th:errors="*{address}" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('address')}" >Invalid address</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Your input field should have `th:field="*{address}"` instead of a `name` attribute. The tis to do proper binding with Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

Did you define a `Validator` in your `@SpringBootApplication`?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: No I didn't. I'm not familiar with validator. Can you give me some tips about validator.

Comment: You don't need that as that is configured out-of-the-box, also validation is working and setup as saving the entity fails (presumably due to the validations).